# Modify code to also consolidate rows rows that aren't right next to each other

Tags: excel, vba

This code does a good job consolidating two rows together (by either summing or appending) based on having the same value in column A. However, it only works on rows that are right next to each other. Trying to figure out how to also make it work for rows that have non-matching rows between them.

Thanks for any input.

```
Sub Consolidate2()

    Worksheets("A").Activate
    
    Columns("I:M").EntireColumn.Delete
    
    
    Dim last_row As Long
        Dim row As Long
        Dim s As Worksheet
        Dim col As Integer
    
    Set s = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A") ' use this line to process a specific sheet
    
        last_row = s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row 'find the last row with data
        
        For row = last_row To 3 Step -1
            If s.Cells(row, "A").Value = s.Cells(row - 1, "A").Value Then
                ' found a match in column A
                
                ' add column G
                s.Cells(row - 1, "G").Value = s.Cells(row - 1, "G").Value + s.Cells(row, "G").Value
                
                ' add column H
                s.Cells(row - 1, "H").Value = s.Cells(row - 1, "H").Value + s.Cells(row, "H").Value
               
                'append all other columns if different
                For col = 1 To 7
                    If Not s.Cells(row, col).Value = s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value Then
                      s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value = s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value & " ~ " & s.Cells(row, col).Value
                    End If
                Next
            
                    ' now delete the duplicate row
                    s.Rows(row).Delete
                End If
            Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: use Match to see if there's a duplicate row (based on ColA) and then combine the two rows if found.

```vb
Sub Consolidate2()

    Dim s As Worksheet, last_row As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim col As Integer, v, m
    
    Set s = Worksheets("A")
    s.Activate
    s.Columns("I:M").EntireColumn.Delete
    last_row = s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row 'find the last row with data
        
    For row = last_row To 3 Step -1
        v = s.Cells(row, "A").Value
        m = Application.Match(v, s.Columns("A"), 0) 'find first match to this row
        If m < row Then                             'earlier row?
            'combine rows `row` and `m`
            s.Cells(m, "G").Value = s.Cells(m, "G").Value + s.Cells(row, "G").Value
            s.Cells(m, "H").Value = s.Cells(m, "H").Value + s.Cells(row, "H").Value
            For col = 1 To 7
                If Not s.Cells(row, col).Value = s.Cells(m, col).Value Then
                  s.Cells(m, col).Value = s.Cells(m, col).Value & _
                                       " ~ " & s.Cells(row, col).Value
                End If
            Next
            s.Rows(row).Delete
        End If 'matched a different row
    Next row
End Sub
```